# My classes are conflicting with each other and I dont know why

Tags: java

So I'm learning java right now and I'm using "sub-programs" just like in C but for some reason when I have both programs it gives me an error "Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException"

Main:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Escreva uma string:");
        String s = SubProgram.string();
        System.out.println("The string " +s);
        System.out.println("Escreva um Int:");
        int i = SubProgram.umInt();
        System.out.println("The int: " +i);    
    }
}
```

Classes:

```
public class SubProgram {
    public static String string() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        scan.close();
        return s;
    }

    public static int umInt(){
        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = scan2.nextInt();
        scan2.close();
        return num;
    }
}
```

If I comment all the "String" class the int one works fine. If I don't comment the String, the String works fine but the int does not

Comment: Closing a Scanner closes the input stream that passes it the data. And once you've closed System.in, it's *really* difficult to open it again. Just pass the scanner to the function.

Comment: You're probably getting the NoSuchElementException because you aren't entering another number/String

Answer (score 1):

First, lets clarify some terms: neither C nor Java actually use the term "sub program", but if you are not a native English speaker this is an understandable error in translation.

What you have in your program is one class - `SubProgram` that has 2 "methods" - `string` and `umInt`.

These names are not very good, since they are too similar to data types.
It would be preferable to use method names like `getString` and `getInt`.

But the real problem is that you are closing `System.in`.
Just like `stdin` in C, `System.in` in Java is a file representing the standard input of your program.

Java has several "wrapper" classes to make working with files more convenient, and `Scanner` is one of them.

However, if you close the `Scanner` wrapping the file, you will also close the file.
Note, that `Scanner` will close not only if you explicitly call `close`, but also if it goes out of scope - this means if you created the `Scanner` object in a method, like you do now, once you exit the method the `Scanner` will close automatically.

This is the part where Java is different from C: there is automatic "cleanup" for a lot of things!

One way to solve your problem is to turn `Scanner` in to a static memeber of the class, like this:

```
public class SubProgram {
    private static final Scanner INPUT = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static String string() {
        String s = INPUT.nextLine();
        return s;
    }

    public static int umInt(){
        int num = INPUT.nextInt();

        return num;
    }
}
```

I added the `final` modifier which is similar to `const` in C.
Since you don't want to change this `Scanner` as long as your program is running, it is better to hold it in a constant.

Also, it is customary to use UPPERCASE for constant names in Java (though it is not required by the language).

- One small note: I used the term "file" for simplicity, but `System.in` is actually a "stream" (object of type `InputStream`).  Streams is how Java deals with things you can read and write like files and sockets, but for now you can think of it as being similar to `FILE *` in C bundled with relevant functions like `fopen`.

Comment: "Note, that Scanner will close not only if you explicitly call close, but also if it goes out of scope"  This latter part is absolutely wrong.  Scanner will close if you explicitly close it or if it's in a [try-with-resources block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), **not** if it goes out of scope.

Comment: @Powerlord `Scanner` overrides the `finalize` method and calls `close` when it is garbage collected. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html Any reference that goes out of scope and does not have a copy elsewhere will be garbage collected (though perhaps not immediately). This is easy to test by simply removing the `close` statements from OP's code, and verifying that the error persists.